# (Win Server 2012) Can't enable Data Deduplication on C: drive

Tags: windows-server-2012, storage, administration, deduplication

I'm trying to enable Data Deduplication on C: drive but Server Manager doesn't allow me to do so. After using PowerShell command it gave me following message:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-Module Deduplication
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-DedupVolume C: -UsageType Default
Enable-DedupVolume : MSFT_DedupVolume.Volume='C:' - HRESULT 0x8056530b, The 
specified volume type is not supported. Deduplication is supported on fixed, write-enabled NTFS data volumes and CSV backed by NTFS data volumes.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-DedupVolume C: -UsageType Default
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: 
    (MSFT_DedupVolume:ROOT/Microsoft/...SFT_DedupVolume) [Enable-DedupVolume], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8056530b,Enable-DedupVolume

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

However this Volume indeed is NTFS, write enabled, fixed Volume. At least I guess so, that's what Server Manager says.

Comment: If you've confirmed that your volume meets all the requirements (we can't tell you if they do, based on what you've provided), then you probably have a corrupted volume. Back up data from it, destroy it, recreate it, restore data, and then try enabling deduplication again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data deduplication is not supported on boot or system drives:

> Deduplication was built for NTFS data volumes and it does not support
>   boot or system drives

[Introduction to Data Deduplication in Windows Server 2012](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2012/05/20/introduction-to-data-deduplication-in-windows-server-2012/)